# LLVM Error: Call parameter type does not match function signature

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

In attempting to get [SwiftAddressBook](https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook/tree/Cocoapods) set up with CocoaPods, compiling gives me the following error:

> Call parameter type does not match function signature!
>   %V16SwiftAddressBook15MultivalueEntry.87* %0 
>   %V16SwiftAddressBook15MultivalueEntry.85*  tail call void
>   @_TFFC16SwiftAddressBook22SwiftAddressBookPersonP33_ECEF355CFD253D8039C191CB27BDAECD24convertMultivalueEntriesFS0_U_Ss9AnyObject__FTGSqGSaGVS_15MultivalueEntryQ____9converterFQ_Q0__GSqGSaGS2_Q0____U_FGS2_Q__GS2_Q0__(%V16SwiftAddressBook15MultivalueEntry.87*
>   noalias sret %0, %V16SwiftAddressBook15MultivalueEntry.86* noalias %3,
>   i8* %.fn.load, %swift.refcounted* %6, %swift.type* %8, %swift.type*
>   %10), !dbg !8665 LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation
>   aborted!

It appears to be complaining about the following [method](https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook/blob/Cocoapods/Pod/Classes/SwiftAddressBookWrapper.swift#L666):

```
private func convertMultivalueEntries<T,U : AnyObject>(multivalue : Array<MultivalueEntry<T>>?, converter : (T) -> U) -> Array<MultivalueEntry<U>>? {
    return multivalue?.map { m -> MultivalueEntry<U> in
        return MultivalueEntry(value: converter(m.value), label: m.label, id: m.id)
    }
}
```

If I forgo the CocoaPods install, and just copy the source into my main project, it compiles just fine.

Is there a way I can simplify this method call so that the LLVM compiler doesn't choke on it? Or have I got the CocoaPod set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to appease the LLVM compiler by removing the use of `map()`, and explicitly typing the return array:

```
private func convertMultivalueEntries<T,U: AnyObject>(multivalue : [MultivalueEntry<T>]?, converter : (T) -> U) -> [MultivalueEntry<U>]? {

    var result: [MultivalueEntry<U>]?
    if let multivalue = multivalue {
        result = []
        for m in multivalue {
            var convertedValue = converter(m.value)
            var converted = MultivalueEntry(value: convertedValue, label: m.label, id: m.id)
            result?.append(converted)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Well, that version crashes at runtime.

Comment: I was wrong, it does not crash. However, it´s just a workaround and does not reveal the true reason for the problem: A bug in the optimization of the compiler!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it´s about the optimization level. Without optimization, Swift is useless, but with optimization switched off, this problem just vanishes. There´s clearly a bug in the compiler!